# group by two columns and adding new key per type in array

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my table:

```
date     | capacity
10/09/13 | 100
10/09/13 | 50
10/09/13 | 100
08/09/13 | 100
```

Low capacity is 50 and high capacity is 100.

I'm trying to retrieve an average capacity per day per capacity type.
So the expected result is:

```
10/09/13
low capacity average: 50
high capacity average: 100

08/09/13
low capacity average: 0
high capacity average: 100
```

My query at the moment is:

**SELECT date, capacity FROM table GROUP BY date, capacity**

What should I add in order to present the customized capacity types (low, high) in array?

Something like:

```
$array = [['date'=>'10/09/13','high_capacity'=>100,'low_capacity'=>50],
                   ['date'=>'08/09/13','high_capacity'=>100,'low_capacity'=>0]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could do the work for you:

```
SELECT date, AVG(capacity) FROM table GROUP BY date ;
```

Or, if you still wish to retrieve min and max values:

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  MIN(capacity) as low_capacity, 
  MAX(capacity) as high_capacity, 
  AVG(capacity) as average_capacity
FROM table 
GROUP BY date ;
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the types to be configurable so I can add medium capacity also. Any idea for something different than MIN and MAX?

Comment: Then you must create another table where you specify `date`, `low_capacity`, `high_capacity`. You just join the tables and get the desired result.

Comment: Then you must create another table where you specify `date`, `low_capacity`, `high_capacity`. You just join the tables and get the desired result.

Comment: Well that's sound reasonable:) Thanks